# Check my code for a multi-dimensional JSON array in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Now, before you all mark this as a duplicate question, please hear me out. I've done ample research on PHP JSON arrays, json_encode and json_decode, yet it's using these functions that have presented a bit of a problem. Consider the following code:

```
<?php

$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$txt = $_POST['txt'];

$ar  = array($uid => array($txt, date("n/j/Y")));
$en  = json_encode($ar); 
echo ar;
$arr = json_decode(ar);
echo $arr->{$uid}->{$txt};

?>
```

I'm trying to create a two-dimension key/value array, encode it, print it, decode it, then retrieve one of the subvalues. My code works up until echoing the subvalue. It just echoes blank. Am I doing this right? I'm kinda new to JSON and all, and any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Does `$ar[$uid][$txt]` work? If not, then you can't expect it to work after JSON encode/decode :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing it as an stdClass Object. use `true` as second parameter in `json_decode` to convert it to `array`.

```
$arr = json_decode($en, true); // make it as array
                   ^^^// here it should be $en not $ar
echo $arr[$uid][0];
```

[Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7Qnak3)

Comment: Oh wow... sorry, that was just a typo. I meant 'echo $en' and then json_decode($en). Any thanks! Your method worked! And, not sure why I figured it would work, but I now realize putting [0] instead of [$txt] would have been a better choice haha.. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: @Nickersoft You are storing values in array is default(numeric) way not as associative array, because of that your method was not working. If you have created array as associative array then your method will work. :)

Answer (score 1):

it should be `echo $arr->{$uid}[0]` at the end. You also have couple of mistakes your passing `ar` to json_deocde() which should be `$en`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ar;
$arr = json_decode(ar);
```

should be

```
echo $ar;
$arr = json_decode($ar);
```